# Does anyone know how to plot the distribution of "Date" in R?

Tags: r, date, distribution

I have a `data.frame` with few columns, some are `characters` and some are `numerics`, one of them is `Date`. I would like to visualize that range of the `Date` but it's not very intuitive how to do that.

Does anyone have any good suggestion for approach? I am not asking for specific codes just the directions of how to get an idea what's the distribution of the Dates are. But if you have codes for demonstrating purpose, I would appreciat that as well.

## Update

Here's a demo code for dates.

```
date3 <- data.frame(example=c(as.Date("01/01/2011", format="%m/%d/%Y"), as.Date("02/01/2012", format="%m/%d/%Y"),  as.Date("03/01/2013", format="%m/%d/%Y")))
```

Comment: please post some of this data here, so I can maybe help you

Comment: Hi @DSGym I have added some example to the original post. Thank you.

Comment: `boxplot(date3)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck this is superb. Simple and straightforward! Thank you.

Comment: I also found that I could do a histogram of a `Date` or `Date-Time` object    
 https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/graphics/html/hist.POSIXt.html

Comment: There are many options e.g. http://www.roymfrancis.com/calendar-plot-with-ggplot2/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to histograms and box plots, it can be useful to see the dates on a calendar.  Building on the example provided by googleVis...

```
library(googleVis)
library(tidyverse)

date4 <- c(as.Date("01/01/2011", format="%m/%d/%Y"), as.Date("02/01/2012", format="%m/%d/%Y"),  as.Date("03/01/2013", format="%m/%d/%Y"))
Date_seq =  seq(from = as.Date('2011-01-01'), to = as.Date('2013-12-31'), by = '1 day')
Dates_of_interest <- rep(0, n = length(Date_seq))
Dates_of_interest[Date_seq %in% date4] <- 1 

df <- data_frame(Date_seq = Date_seq, Dates_of_interest = Dates_of_interest)

Cal <- gvisCalendar(df, 
                    datevar="Date_seq", 
                    numvar="Dates_of_interest",
                    options=list(
                      title="Dates of interest",
                      height=320,
                      calendar="{yearLabel: { fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                               fontSize: 32, color: '#1A8763', bold: true},
                               cellSize: 10,
                               cellColor: { stroke: 'red', strokeOpacity: 0.2 },
                               focusedCellColor: {stroke:'red'}}")
)
plot(Cal)
```

[image]